# What are the different chromeoptions for webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng, chrome-options

For the ChromeOptions class in selenium, how can I find out all the keys like *profile.default_content_settings.popups*, *download.default_directory* which I can use with chromeoptions class to perform browser specific setting.

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String,Object> prefs = new HashMap<String,Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups",0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory","C:\\User\\Desktop\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

"Use the Source, Luke!" :)

The best and most up-to-date info is really in the source, which is very well documented.

All preferences: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Bonus - all switches: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc